# Center aligning text for Listview in JqMobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I want to center align the text in listviews with the help of a specific class in jquery mobile css...

I have the following code...

```
<li><a href="index.html" data-icon="false" class="">Home</a></li>
```

or i build a new class for it using my custom css...??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to override the following in your custom.css

```
#myList .ui-btn-inner {
    text-align: center;
}
```

While you can add above in jqm.css; it would be a better approach to keep your customizations/overrides in a separate css file.

For JQM 1.4.5 (latest as of 26-Nov-14)

```
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @AriWais I have modified the answer specifying the class to be overridden in the latest JQM version.